# Haskell Implementation of Bell Numbers

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, factorial, type-mismatch

I'm trying to implement a bell number finder + summation in Haskell. I'm fairly confident that my methods are correct, but I'm having problems with some errors at compile time. My current error message is:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( survey2.hs, survey2.o )
survey2.hs:5:14:**
    Expected a constraint, but ‘Integer’ has kind ‘*’
    In the type signature for ‘binomial’:
      binomial :: (Integer, Integer) => Integer

survey2.hs:15:12:
    Expected a constraint, but ‘Integer’ has kind ‘*’
    In the type signature for ‘bellSum’: bellSum :: Integer => Integer**
```

I'm totally new to haskell and new to functional languages in general. Based on this error, I have tried changing my "function definitions" (Or whatever you call them in Haskell), but I just seem to cause more errors.

The end goal of the program is to print the sum of the bell numbers 0-9.

```
factorial n
  | n <= 1    = 1 
  | otherwise =  n * factorial(n-1)

binomial :: (Integer, Integer) => Integer
binomial n k 
  | k > n     = 0 
  | k < 0     = 0 
  | otherwise = factorial(n) / factorial(n-k) * factorial(k)

bell n
  | n <= 1    = 1 
  | otherwise = sum [ binomial (n-1, k-1)  * bell (k-1) | k<-[0..n-1] ] 

bellSum :: Integer => Integer  
bellSum n = sum [ bell(k) | k<-[0..n] ]

main = bell(9 :: Integer)
```

Comment: The symbol for a function type is `->`, not `=>`.  `=>` is for typeclass constraints (which I guess you haven't learned about yet).

Comment: And a definition for an `(Integer, Integer) -> Integer` function looks like `binomial (n,k) = ...`.  The one you have corresponds to an `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` function (which, in haskell, is a much more common pattern).

Comment: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is highly recommended.

Comment: `factorial(n) / factorial(n-k) * factorial(k)` is equal to `(factorial(n) / factorial(n-k)) * factorial(k)` not `factorial(n) / (factorial(n-k) * factorial(k))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is not consistent (`=>` should be `->`)

```
binomial :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
binomial n k
```

either change to

```
binomial :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
binomial n k
```

or

```
binomial :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
binomial (n, k)
```

Another hint for you, you can compute binomial without the factorial function (or even multiplication)

```
binomial n k | k==0 || k==n = 1
             | k==1 = n
             | otherwise = binomial (n-1) (k-1) + binomial (n-1) k
```

this is still very inefficient but it can be memoized.

Comment: Thank you. Any major advantages/disadvantages to the Integer -> Integer -> Integer vs (Integer, Integer) -> Integer? I my program to the (n, k) and now I'm getting a different, issue with the same program. Should I open a new question or modify the existing one? Not really sure on proper etiquette for the question.

Comment: if the two arguments are not naturally is a pair better to use `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` which will be more natural in Haskell and more flexible.